# How long is an Argentinian visa valid?

Tags: visas, argentina, algerian-citizens

I am an Algerian citizen living in France, and I would like to visit Argentina. Flights are really expensive from Paris, but sometimes there are some real good promotions.

I thought about making my visa application with a flight booking (which will not be my real flight) and once my visa is issued, take the next flight to Argentina for a reasonable price.

My concern is that I'm afraid my visa would only be valid during the period of stay I'll mention in my application (for example from 1st to 15th of January), so I'd be obliged to travel to Argentina during the period mentioned in the filled form!

Does anybody know if Argentina issues tourist visas for 3-6 months like Schengen states do, or if it's specific for the period mentioned on the form?

Comment: _A sidenote: it is not true that Schengen state issue visas for 3-6 months. They very often issue them for the specific dates on your application._

Comment: Thanks for the note, I didn't know that. I've never seen a Schengen visa for less than 3 months, at least for algerian citizens. Good for my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Ministry of the Interior Immigration Department](http://www.migraciones.gov.ar/accesible/indexN.php?categorias), a tourist visa is issued for up to a period of three months, and may be extended while in Argentina:

> **Tourists**
>
> ARTICLE 24 SECTION a) LAW 25,871, DECREE 616/2010
>
> A foreigner who obtains from the National Immigration Office an admission in such character shall be considered a transient resident.
>
> TOURIST: Any foreigner who enters the country for the purpose of rest or recreation, with a period of authorized stay of up to THREE (3) MONTHS EXTENDABLE FOR ANOTHER SIMILAR PERIOD.
>
> EXTENSION: it can be done at the National Directorate of Migration, from 8 a.m. to 2:00 p.m., building 4 sector, extensions, or in the delegations and immigration offices in the interior of the country.
>
> Requests for extension of residence, as well as the request for change of category or migratory subcategory, must be made within SIXTY (60) days prior to the expiration of the temporary residence and within TEN (10) days prior to the expiration of the term. temporary residence.
>
> The foreigner who presents himself spontaneously and voluntarily within THIRTY (30) days of the expiration of the periods foreseen in the previous point, will suffer a surcharge of FIFTY PER CENT (50%) of the amount of the rate foreseen for the extension procedure of residence or for the change of category or subcategory of migration.
>
> Requirements:
>
> - Valid passport or valid Identity Card, Identity Card, National Identity Document or Alien Registration Card (DEC CMC No. 37/14) (MERCOSUR and associated countries).
> - MERCOSUR renewal fee: $ 900. NON MERCOSUR $ 2700.  Argentina, Brazil, Paraguay and Uruguay.
> - Current temporary residence *
> - The period of permanence has expired, SUCH RESIDENCE CAN NOT BE EXTENDED in order to leave the national territory, you must request an ENTRY ENTRY.
>
> ENTRY OF DEPARTURE: can be processed at the National Directorate of Migration, from 8 to 20 hours, building 4 sector General Directorate of Migration Movement, or in the delegations and immigration offices in the interior of the country.
>
> IMPORTANT: (10) consecutive days from the day following the date on which such authorization was issued, during that period you must leave the country; If this period expires, you must request a new exit authorization and pay again.
>
> Requirements:
>
> - Valid passport, valid Identity Card or current National Identity Document of your country of origin, (the latter with the countries Brazil. , Bolivia, Uruguay, Paraguay, Chile, Peru, Venezuela, Ecuador and Colombia).
> - Enabling rate
>
> [See table of current rates](http://www.migraciones.gov.ar/pdf_varios/tasas/decreto_modificacion_tasas.pdf) 
>   [See more of Enabling Output](http://www.migraciones.gov.ar/accesible/indexA.php?habilitacion_salida)

Mercosur is made up of four member countries — Argentina, Brazil, Paraguay, and Uruguay